# Calculate average and total from file

Tags: python

Python beginner. 
How do I present data from a file and calculate total/average for each person? 
How do I add the value to a variable outside of for in every iteration, and once the iteration is over divide it by the number of records?

The data in the file varies since the user can add and delete data, but the data is structured like this:

```
PersonA;342;454;559;
PersonB;444;100;545;
PersonC;332;567;491;
PersonD;142;612;666;
```

I wanna present it like this:

```
PersonA    342    454     559    TOTAL   AVERAGE
PersonB    444    100     545    TOTAL   AVERAGE
PersonC    332    567     491    TOTAL   AVERAGE
PersonD    142    612     666    TOTAL   AVERAGE
```

What can I write after this to get it right?

```
def show_result():
    text_file = open('result.txt', 'r')

    for line in text_file:
        if ';' in line:
            line2 = line.split(";")
        print line2
```

?

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:

s = """PersonA;342;454;559;
PersonB;444;100;545;
PersonC;332;567;491;
PersonD;142;612;666;"""

for line in s.split("\n"):
    p, a, b, c, _ = line.strip().split(";")
    print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(p, a, b, c,
      sum([int(a), int(b), int(c)]),
      sum([int(a), int(b), int(c)]) / 3))
```

solution:

```
def show_result():
    text_file = open('minigolf.txt', 'r')

    print "Name,Round1,Round2,Round3"
    for line in text_file:
        if ';' in line:
            line2 = line.split(";")[:-1]
        print line2

        line_total = sum(map(int, line2[1:]))
        line_average = line_total / len(line2[1:])
        print "Total: ", line_total
        print "Average: ", line_average
```

Comment: How are total and average calculated for each person? Do you mean the total/average of columns 2, 3, and 4?

Answer (score 2):

```
s = """PersonA;342;454;559;
PersonB;444;100;545;
PersonC;332;567;491;
PersonD;142;612;666;"""

for line in s.split("\n"):
    p, a, b, c, _ = line.strip().split(";")
    print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(p, a, b, c,
      sum([int(a), int(b), int(c)]),
      sum([int(a), int(b), int(c)]) / 3))
```

Output:

```
PersonA 342     454     559     1355    451.6666666666667
PersonB 444     100     545     1089    363.0
PersonC 332     567     491     1390    463.3333333333333
PersonD 142     612     666     1420    473.3333333333333
```

**Edit:**

If you want to read from a file, you can do this:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # same as above: split the line, etc.
```

Comment: But does this get the data from a file? The data is stored in result.txt like PersonA;342;454;559;

Comment: My explanation might be a bit unclear. Since the user can delete and add data in result.txt, PersonA might not exist but PersonQ might one time, but not the next. 
How do I get the data from the file, get it into different lines and calculate total/average when I don't know which persons exists in the file from time to time?

Comment: You can rerun the calculation with the changed file. It will pick up every person that is mentioned in the file *now*.

Comment: Please don't put code, especially Python code, into a comment. It is unreadable.

Comment: OK, sorry. I've updated the description if you wanna have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the `total` you can simply do (assuming that you don't want to include the first index, which contains "PersonA", etc.):

```
line_total = sum(map(int, line2[1:]))
```

From there, the average is also simple:

```
line_average = line_total / len(line2[1:])
```

Explanation:

- The `sum` function takes in an iterable (for our purposes think of an iterable as a list) and adds all of its contents using the appropriate sum function.
- The `[1:]` is called list splicing. Using this syntax you're telling Python you want to create a new list with the contents of the original list starting at the `1` position. Here's a couple of examples:

  ```
  >>> a = [1, 2, 3]
  >>> b = [1:]
  >>> b
  [2, 3]
  ```

The specific syntax is as follows: `[start_index : end_index]` either the `start_index` or the `end_index` can be left blank and Python will fill them in with the start or end of the list respectively.

Comment: Beware that the input is strings, not ints.

Comment: But how would this look together with the code I've written, cause now I get an error:   File "C:\Users\HKI\Desktop\test3.py", line 32, in show_result
    line_total = sum(map(int, line2[1:]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0):

This how I would do. That said, there are many ways to get this done in Pyhton.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('result.txt', sep=';',header=None)
del df[4]
df['AVERAGE'] = df[[1,2,3]].mean(axis = 1)
df['TOTAL'] = df[[1,2,3]].sum(axis = 1)
```

I use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library for this type of operations.

Output:

```
    0           1       2       3       AVERAGE     TOTAL
0   PersonA     342     454     559     451.666667  1355
1   PersonB     444     100     545     363.000000  1089
2   PersonC     332     567     491     463.333333  1390
3   PersonD     142     612     666     473.333333  1420
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any values per person, and for any number of persons:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def myprint(lines):
    sum_dict = defaultdict(lambda: ([], 0, 0))

    for line in lines:
        data = line.strip().split(";")
        person = data[0].strip()
        values = [int(i) for i in data[1:] if i]
        sum_dict[person] = (values + sum_dict[person][0], sum(values)+sum_dict[person][1], len(values)+sum_dict[person][2])

    for person in sorted(sum_dict):
        values, total, nb = sum_dict[person]
        print "{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(person, '\t'.join([str(i) for i in values]), total, total/nb)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import os
    if os.path.exists('result.txt'):
        with open('result.txt') as input:
            lines = input.readlines()
    else:
        s = """PersonA;342;454;559;
               PersonB;444;100;545;
               PersonC;332;567;491;
               PersonD;142;612;666;"""
        lines = s.split('\n')

    myprint(lines)
```