# Calculate total/average: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

The user can delete and add data in result.txt, PersonA might not exist but PersonQ might one time, but not the next. How do I get the data from the file, get it into different lines and calculate total/average when I don't know which persons exists in the file from time to time?:

```
PersonA;342;454;559;
PersonB;444;100;545;
PersonC;332;567;491;
PersonD;142;612;666;
```

I wanna present it like this:

```
PersonA    342    454     559    TOTAL   AVERAGE
PersonB    444    100     545    TOTAL   AVERAGE
PersonC    332    567     491    TOTAL   AVERAGE
PersonD    142    612     666    TOTAL   AVERAGE
```

What can I write after this to get it right?

```
def show_result():
    text_file = open('result.txt', 'r')

    for line in text_file:
        if ';' in line:
            line2 = line.split(";")
        print line2
```

I want to use this:

```
line_total = sum(map(int, line2[1:]))
line_average = line_total / len(line2[1:])
```

But recieve error message:

```
File "C:\Users\HKI\Desktop\test3.py", line 32, in show_result
    line_total = sum(map(int, line2[1:]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Don't wanna use Panda or similar.

Comment: Error is clear you're trying to convert an empty string `''` to an `int` you need to look at your data or debug your code a little more

Comment: try this `line_total = sum(map(int, line2[1:-1]))`.

Comment: Please post your errors in the initial question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451962/calculate-average-and-total-from-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change `line2 = line.split(";")` to `line2 = line.split(";")[:-1]`,then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

All the lines contain a trailing `';'` which adds an empty character to the end of the split. An attempt to convert the empty string `''` to `int` raises that error.

You should do a *right strip* on the last semi-colon before splitting:

```
line = line.strip() # remove new line character and white spaces
line2 = line.rstrip(';').split(";")
```